# Next Permutation definition

Tags: c++, arrays, permutation

Implement the next permutation, which rearranges numbers into the numerically next greater permutation of numbers for a given array A of size N.

If such arrangement is not possible, it must be rearranged as the lowest possible order i.e., sorted in an ascending order.

The test cases of this problem include :

Input :
    `A = [20, 50, 113]`

Output :
    `[20, 113, 50]`

How is `[20, 113, 50]`  greater than `[20, 50, 113]`?

Similarly , 
Input :
    `A = [5, 18, 9]`

Output :
    `[9, 5, 18]`

How is this next permutation rather than `[5,9,18]`?

Comment: The word "numerically" is a bit confusing; "lexically" is what they mean.

Comment: And to solve this, we have [std::next_permutation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation).

Comment: I don't know if it's helpful for anyone else, but I had the same basic question - "Yes but what does the permutation actually DO? What does it accomplish?" - and I had the same question as you about `[5, 18, 9]`. Then, somewhere in my research, someone said "odometer" and it immediately clicked. If the numbers given are numbers on an old-style mechanical odometer, what's the next highest odometer reading that uses ONLY those characters? ie. in the `[5, 18, 9]` case, the next odometer reading would be `9-5-18` (assuming the odometer could show 2-digit numbers). Hope it helps!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> How is [20, 113, 50] greater than [20, 50, 113]?

Because it's *lexicographically* greater than, this works as follows:

1. If the first item is greater than or less than then this is the result.
2. Otherwise if they're equal then if the second item is greater than or less than then this is the result.
3. Otherwise if they're equal then if the third item is greater than or less than then this is the result.
4. Otherwise they're equal.

So `[20, 113, 50] > [20, 50, 113]` because in step 1: `20 == 20` and in step 2: `113 > 50`.

Likewise: `[5, 9, 18] < [5, 18, 9]` because `9 < 18` and `[9, 5, 18] > [5, 18, 9]` because `9 > 5`.

Comment: Lexicographically makes sense,got it.But every where in question the term used is Numerically.

Comment: @ArunRNambiar That's confusing, they should have been clearer.

Answer (score 0):

1. > How is [20, 113, 50] greater than [20, 50, 113]?

   In `[20, 50, 113]`, the last increasing length-2 interval is `[50, 113]`, then we pick the first element in `[113, 113]`(eq. to `[113]`) **from right to left** so that it is greater than `50`. Swap it with `50`, then reverse the interval `(50, 113]`, This will give you `[20, 113, 50]`.
2. > Output : `[9, 5, 18]`\n How is this next permutation rather than [5,9,18]?

   From `A = [5, 18, 9]` Found `[5, 18]`,
   From `[18, 9]` Found `9`,
   Swap(`5`,`9`) Get `[9, 18, 5]`,
   Reverse(`[18, 5]`) Get `[5, 18]`,
   So you get: `[9, 5, 18]`.

Answer (score 0):

the next permutation means the next largest number

ex-- like if an array is arr = {1, 2, 3, 6, 5, 4}

then the number is 123654

its next greater element is 124356;

so return the array {1, 2, 4, 3, 5, 6}.